# Mapbox.js and geojson-vt

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I have a GeoJSON with ~10000 polygons (80MB).
I saw that best solution is geojson-vt but when I use with Mapbox.js map I need to wait until that file loaded. But when I use drop section on map and put that file in there these polygons are fast draw.
Maybe I set something wrong or I don't know. maybe somebody has a better solution for large dataset.

Thanks,
Darko